# Error when executing Canopy's Pythonwin.exe (wincon32 module not found)

Tags: enthought, canopy

I'm sorry if my title doesn't make sense but that's the problem I'm having.

When executing a script at the command line, (or by double-clicking on it)  using `C:\pythonwin.exe SomeApp.pyw`, I get a popup error box saying
`ImportError: No module named wincon32.` (Full error message at the bottom)

Just executing pythonwin.exe by itself with or without a script also has the same effect.

Google is amazingly bereft of any knowledge of wincon32. Trying to install wincon32 module with `pip install wincon32` just says "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement wincon32 (from version: ) No matching distribution found for wincon32"

pythonwin.exe is in the system's PATH.

Thanks for any help. Below is the full contents of the popup error box.

Title - Python Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "string", Line 1 in module

File "C:\Users\Me\Canopy(Python)\User\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin
\framework\startup.py", line 49, in  _import_(moduleName)

File "C:\Users\Me\Canopy(Python)\User\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin
\framework\intpyapp.py", line 3, in  import wincon32

ImportError: No module named wincon32
```

(I'm using Windows 10 x64)

Answer (score 0):

Where did `c:\Pythonwin.exe` come from? It's not part of any Canopy installation that I've ever heard of. If you're trying to run Canopy Python, see https://support.enthought.com/entries/23646538-Make-Canopy-User-Python-be-your-default-Python

Comment: A quick google for "wincon32" finds only malware references. In your shoes, I would be concerned. What instructions have you been following, and/or from where have you been downloading software?

Comment: Maybe you copied pythonwin.exe (part of the pywin32 package) to `c:\ ` for convenience?

Comment: If, as I suspect, you did copy pythonwin.exe to `C:\ `, then I wouldn't worry much about malware, I'd just say "don't do that". First, it's not "Canopy's pythonwin.exe". It's part of the Pywin32 package, which is provided for its libraries, but with no expectation that you'll be able to use its executables, nor support for doing so. Second, even if you can use that executable, you should run it from where it lives, because it is likely looking for the other files in that directory, which might account for the error message that you reported.